# 32 bit color version of TImageList for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, colors, transparency, delphi-7

I'm hoping someone knows of an enhanced TImageList for Delphi 7 that supports 32 bit (alpha channel) bitmaps (for a TTreeView).  Ideally free .  Or perhaps how to extend/configure the stock TImageList to handle the alpha channel properly in 32 bit color bitmaps.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ColorDepth property to 32bit?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, failed to notice that part.  

Just another reason to upgrade.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

thany.org had a package called PNGComponents that included a TPNGImageList that handled 32-bit alpha-blended images.  You also had to have [PNGImage](http://pngimage.codeplex.com/) installed.

Hmm, I can't get to thany.org, but Uwe Raabe updated the set to D2009/D2010.  It's available as [QC #26127](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127), and should be compatible down to Delphi 7 as long as you get the aforementioned PNGImage component first.

Comment: It does work with Delphi 7. The critical point is to get hands on PNGImage as this is not part of the package.